# getting object with unknown generic parameter from map <String, Table<? extends Entity>>

Tags: java, generics

I have

```
public class Entity
```

On which works class:

```
public class Table<Target extends Entity>
{
    public boolean save (Target target)
    public Target load (int id)
}
```

Till i put this objects of Table class in Database class Map everything is ok but:

```
public class Database
{
    public String name;
    public Map<String, Table<? extends Entity>> tables = new HashMap <String, Table<? extends Entity>> ();
    public Context context;
    public int version;
    public Database (Context context, int version)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.version = version;
    }
    public void add (Table<? extends Entity> table)
    {
        tables.put(table.name, table);
    }
    public Table <? extends Entity> table (String name)
    {
        return (Table<? extends Entity>) tables.get(name);
    }

}
```

Assume we have:

```
 public class Apple extends Entity
```

I want this code to work:

```
    //init      
    database = new Database(getBaseContext(), 4);
    new Table<Apple> (database, Apple.class);

    //this is where solution need occurs !
    database.table("apples").save (new Apple("green apple"));
```

**The method save(capture#1-of ? extends Entity) in the type 
Table(capture#1-of ? extends Entity) 
 is not applicable for the arguments (Note)**

How to make the map.get method work ?

Comment: This is impossible in Java's type system. (And I've yet to encounter a type system where this would work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do to make this more convenient is map the tables by the target class:

```
Map<Class<? extends Entity>, Table<? extends Entity>> tables;

public void <T extends Entity> addTable(Class<T> cls, Table<T> table) {
    tables.put(cls, table);
    // alternately make it possible to get the target class from the table
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Entity> Table<T> getTable(Class<T> cls) {
    return (Table<T>) tables.get(cls);
}
```

As the annotation implies, this isn't at all typesafe - you'll need to make sure you never mismatch the keys and values in `tables`.

Comment: dont know yet why adding class in the map key solved problem but it works. you are my hero.

Comment: @BioHazard It doesn't solve the problem of type safety, it just makes the Java compiler stop complaining by enabling the unsafe cast in `table()`. It's still possible to do `tables.put(Orange.class, new Table<Apple>(Apple.class));` and cause bugs down the road when you do `table(Orange.class);`, which returns a `Table<Orange>`, except the actual object will fetch `Apple`s from the DB. So it's a hack that requires some amount of care to use.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to user millimoose i modified database class:

```
public class Database
{
    public String name;
    public Map<Class<? extends Entity>, Table<? extends Entity>> tables = new HashMap <Class<? extends Entity>, Table<? extends Entity>> ();
    public Context context;
    public int version;
    public Database (Context context, String name, int version)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.context = context;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public <Target extends Entity> void add (Class<Target> target, Table<Target> table) 
    {
        tables.put(target, table);
    }   

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <Target extends Entity> Table<Target> table (Class<Target> target) 
    {
        return (Table<Target>) tables.get (target);
    }   
}
```

and after that it was possible to use it like that:

```
    database = new Database(getBaseContext(),"notes", 1);
    database.add (Note.class, new Table<Note> (database, Note.class));


    database.table(Note.class).save (new Note("first note"));
    database.table(Note.class).save (new Note("second note"));
    database.table(Note.class).save (new Note("best note"));

    items.addAll(database.table(Note.class).load());
```

It seems I have no enough skills yet to know why it worked but adding (Class(? extends Entity) in map key solved problem.